# How to search for string in files whose name contains another string and are created in last 7 days in linux?

Tags: linux, string, grep, find

I'd like to search for string in files whose name contains another string and are created in last 7 days,

I tried:

```
find . -type f -name '*name_string*' -mtime -7 | grep -ir '*mytext*'
```

But it didn't work,

Please help

Comment: describe "it didn't work"

Comment: It didn't work = It didn't find any files.

Comment: `-mtime` does not give you creation time of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close but just missed the `xargs`, otherwise the output from `find` is just a bunch of text for grep.

```
find . -type f -name '*name_string*' -mtime -7 | xargs grep -i 'mytext'
```

By using `xargs` you pass the list of files as the set of files that `grep` should be searching for the string `mytext`.

BTW, you can just use `mytext` instead of `*mytext*`

If you want to search for multiple patterns say `pattern1` and `pattern2` in the list of file names containing `name_string`:

```
find . -type f -name '*name_string*' -mtime -7 -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do
    grep -qi pattern1 "$f" && grep -li pattern2 "$f"
done
```

This should work even with file names containing spaces.

Comment: OK, How about I'm searching for files that contain 2 strings together with same criteria? I mean: `find . -type f -name '*name_string*' -mtime -7 | xargs grep -i '*mytext_1*' AND '*mytext_2*'`

Comment: You should be able to do that using the extended regular expression syntax using `-E` with `grep`. Do you want 2 strings to be in the same line in the file or could be anywhere in the file ?

Comment: Could be anywhere in the file.

Answer (score 1):

No need for xargs or other non-standard extension to have good file name handling:

```
find . -type f -name '*name_string*' -mtime -7 -exec grep -i 'mytext' {} \;
```